# Is it possible to fit a piecewiseSEM model with datasets of different sizes?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, structural-equation-modeling

I'm trying to compare different **piecewiseSEM** models  in R evaluating the factors that directly and indirectly influence the difference in median sizes of cohorts from one year to the next. My terminal endogenous variable is "growth" (median size age t+1 - median size age t) as a length-growth residual, but I will continue to call it "growth" for ease of explanation. I have growth values for 32 annual cohorts with 3 ages within each cohort separated for the 2 sexes. I don't have a balanced data set in the sense that I don't always have a growth value for each age within each cohort for both sexes. However, I treat each growth estimate as a replicate for reasons that I don't need to get into but, basically, growth does not appear to differ due to age during these 3 ages of this species' life. I accounted for the effect of sex by manually performing the steps for the command `multigroup` - that was a separate issue that I couldn't resolve, but I followed how it is described here: (https://jslefche.github.io/sem_book/multigroup-analysis.html#multigroup-analysis-using-local-estimation).

The most comprehensive model in my piecewiseSEM includes relationships with environmental conditions during the year of sampling, conditions during early life for the cohort, and previous median growth or size of the individuals within the cohort:

```
psem1 <- psem(

  lmer(growth ~ growth.lastyr + prop.mature + CDD + Prey + Sex.binary * Percent.Ice + (1 | Year), data = varsGrowthscaled),

  lmer(growth.lastyr ~ Sex.binary + Age.0.length + (1 | Year), data = varsGrowthscaled),

  lm(Age.0.length ~ Percent.Ice + CDD_May, data = Cohort.vars)

)
```

Terms:

- "growth.lastyr" is the growth value for the previous age within that cohort (*unique to year of sampling*)
- "prop.mature" is the proportion of individuals in the cohort at that age that are mature (*unique to year of sampling*)
- "CDD" is the cumulative degree days for the previous year (*unique to year of sampling*)
- "Prey" is a measure of per-capita prey density  (*unique to year of sampling*)
- "Sex.binary" is a binary term allowing a comparison of female vs. male responses (0 = females, 1 = males) and modeled it as a numeric variable as per: https://jslefche.github.io/sem_book/categorical-variables.html#introduction-to-exogenous-categorical-variables
- "Percent.Ice" is the percent of ice covering the lake during Feb-March of the year the cohort was hatched (*unique to each cohort*)
- "Year" is the year individuals were caught  (*unique to year of sampling*)
- "Age.0.length" is the median length of individuals in the cohort when they were caught during the year they hatched (*unique to each cohort*)
- "CDD_May" is the cumulative degree days during the month of May of the year they hatched (*unique to each cohort*)

As you can see, the last model in psem1 uses a different data frame than the previous two. This was my attempt to avoid duplicating values for each age and sex of a cohort, but, obviously, it asks the model to fit data of different lengths. **Is this OK to do?** I can make the model run and the degrees of freedom look appropriate for each variable in each model, but I know that doesn't always mean I'm doing what I think I'm doing.

If that is not OK to do, I have the following alternative, but some aspects of it are potentially more concerning. If the above is OK, skip to the next section because I have follow-up questions.

```
psem1alt <- psem(
 
  lmer(growth ~ growth.lastyr + prop.mature + CDD + Prey + Sex.binary * Percent.Ice + (1 | Year), data = varsGrowthscaled),

  lmer(growth.lastyr ~ Sex.binary + Age.0.length + (1 | Year), data = varsGrowthscaled),

  lmer(Age.0.length ~ Percent.Ice + CDD_May + (1 | Sex.block), data = varsGrowthscaled),

  )
```

Since I have no variation due to sex in the final model (all the values are duplicated identically for sex), I get singularity warnings `boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular`, but the model does eventually run (after 3 failed attempts) and I get output that somewhat makes sense. However, I am still duplicating values in the last model with up to 3 identical values for Age.0.lenth, Percent.Ice, and CDD_May being represented for each age of each cohort. I tried including a random intercept of Cohort in the last model too, but I get failed convergence because the `Model is nearly unidentifiable: very large eigenvalue`. If I run it as a linear model without any random effect, everything works fine, but I have dramatically, artificially increased my sample size for those relationships.

If my first option was reasonable, how do you suggest comparing that model with another when I remove the direct relationships with Age.0.length? I attempted to do the following:

```
psem2 <- psem(
 
  lmer(growth ~ growth.lastyr + prop.mature + CDD + Prey + Sex.binary * Percent.Ice + (1 | Year), data = varsGrowthscaled),

  lmer(growth.lastyr ~ Sex.binary + Age.0.length + (1 | Year), data = varsGrowthscaled),
 
  Cohort.vars$Age.0.length ~ 1,
  
  Cohort.vars$Percent.Ice ~ 1,
  
  Cohort.vars$CDD_May
 
)
```

I received the following error:

`Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : arguments imply differing number of rows: 153, 0`

Does anyone have suggestions for how to best approach this? Is it possible to fit models using different data frames with piecewiseSEM? Is it possible to then compare modified psem objects with AICc? Alternatively, are there ways to account for duplicated values that would occur if I used the same data frame for all models within my psem?

I'm happy to share the data or more code if that would help answer this question.

Comment: I don't have a specific answer, but are you familiear with the integrative data analysis literature? This sounds like this sort of problem.  There was a special issue of Psychological Methods on this in 2009. https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/19485623/

Comment: I am not familiar with the integrative data analysis literature. I'll take a look at this paper and see if I can find anything useful for this problem. Thanks!